# What's a professional synonym for "would love to"?

Tags: american-english, expressions

I frequently use the expression "I would love to" when I write e-mails to request things from the other party. As in "`I would love to have a call to discuss...`" I feel like it conveys humility, expressing that the other party would be doing me a favor by accepting the call, for instance, which is useful for sales.

However, it was pointed out to me that this may not be very professional, because it has the word "love" in it. Are there any similar constructs that can convey the similar subtlety of the expression, while still sounding more professional?

Expressions like "`I would like to..`" clearly don't make the cut..

Comment: The "love" in "I would love to" has little to do with the "love" in "I love you"; the second one is expressing a personal emotion that is (arguably) unprofessional, while the first one is expressing enthusiasm for an event or an activity. "I love my job" or "I love making clients happy", when spoken without sarcasm, are exceedingly professional.

Comment: @S.G. correct. Yet in some cultural contexts (non-native speakers, for example) the difference might not be clear. Assuming this is the case with OP, their request for alternative phrases is more than understandable.

Comment: I hope saying "I would love to" is not unprofessional, because if it is, I've been unprofessional my whole 19-year career, so far. No one has ever suggested I stop using that phrase. If you're customer facing, talking about yourself and using the word "I" a lot isn't necessarily ideal. So you could consider asking what would work best for the customer, and making sure the word "you" appears in the question, e.g., "when would you like to discuss this?"

Comment: How about "I would be happy to discuss with you" or "I would be happy to set up a time when we could discuss this in detail"?

Comment: I think it is acceptable. It shows your honesty and people appreciate that.

Comment: You can use:
It is our/my interest to...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

My verb of choice would be **[appreciate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appreciate)**.

It conveys all aspects you want to express: a polite request, valuing the other party's time and effort and a gratefulness for their contribution.

Comment: So instead of "I would love to have a call to discuss collaboration opportunities", use "I would appreciate a call to discuss collaboration opportunities" ? I somehow feel like the former is more "active" because of the action verb. What do you think?

Comment: @user1496984, that would be a request to the other person to call you, but basically, yes.

Comment: There's a danger with making a request in this indirect way, which is that there's a fine line between expressing enthusiasm for the call, and coming across as sarcastically giving an instruction. "I would love to have a call" is IMO more polite than "I would appreciate a call". The latter to me can come across as, "the very least you could do is have this call" or even "I am entitled to a call". I speak British English in case that makes a difference.

Comment: @SteveJessop: That is for a large part because of a lack of context. If you're offered a clear favor, above what's reasonable to expect, then appreciation is not at all sarcastic. If however the offer is just meeting basic expectations, "appreciation" is sarcastic precisely because it's you're responding as if it were a favor. This is not unique to "appreciation", any form of clearly misplaced gratitude is sarcastic. c.f. "Thanks Obama".

Answer (score 11):

I don't know why you said ***I would like to...*** "clearly doesn't make the cut", because it is precisely the expression you need to use in a formal context such as a work email. When you are making a request, "like" is way more polite than "love", and "like" doesn't have any of the connotations that would make "love" unsuitable regardless of politeness or lack thereof.

> I would like to have a call to discuss the new project. Would Wednesday at 2:00 work for you?

Comment: Interesting. To me, writing "I would like to have a call" seems to bossy, almost authoritarian.. But then again, I'm not a native speaker, so maybe it's OK.

Comment: I agree with both answers. Both *appreciate* and *would like* work. To user1496984 (the OP), if you want to show strong enthusiasm (which you may probably have when you say *'d love to*), you could also use *I would like very much to*, e.g., *I would like very much to schedule a meeting with you to review both my performance and my request.* (The example was taken from *AMA Handbook of Business Letters*, 4th Edition.)

Comment: @user1496984 Maybe this is a difference of culture or training, but (in relation to your comment on Stephie's answer) I hear "I would appreciate..." as having more of the negative connotations you apply to "I would like to..." here. Perhaps because its usage in more formal settings is often a subtle complaint? "I don't like *this* and would prefer *that*."

Comment: @user1496984: it can do, for example if you go into a coffee shop and say "I would like to have an espresso" then that's perfectly polite but you're correct that it's closer to an instruction than a request, because you don't expect it to be declined. But without that context "I would like to have a call" can be read either way, as "please can I have a call" or as "my irrefutable will is that we shall have a call" :-)

Comment: can use 'I would welcome...' at some places in the text

Answer (score 9):

"It would be great if we could..."

Seems like it will fit the bill to me. Slightly stronger than "I would like to..." and slightly weaker than "I would love to..."

Comment: Also, I think the passive voice and switch to "we" instead of "I" helps neutralize/formalize it.

Comment: This seems to be the "professional" way of expressing enthusiasm about whatever is discussed. Without the "great" part, some of the feeling is lost. "Greatly appreciated" and the like can have the same function.

Comment: My colleagues use "it would be great if" to mean anything between "the ideal for me is" and "the company will be bankrupt tomorrow unless". It's fine for politeness but not necessarily very informative :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop I think many folks consider politeness inversely proportional to the amount of information conveyed. Isn't giving someone too much information at once a form of [micro-aggression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microaggression_theory) ? :)

Answer (score 6):

I don't understand why somebody would point out "would love to" or "would like to" may not be very professional. They are perfectly fine in any business context. An expression like

> I would be much obliged if we could have a call to discuss XYZ.

will be considered unnecessarily formal. It doesn't mean you can't use this expression. You can use this expression if you are dealing with high authorities or if you are asking for a special favor.

The most common expression would be

> I would appreciate (it) if we could have a call to discuss XYZ.

Again, this could be considered a little formal.

You can just say

> Please let me know what time is/would be most convenient for you to discuss XYZ.

or

> Please give me a call to discuss XYZ when it is convenient for you.

Using just "please" is simple, polite, and it is not unprofessional at all.

Comment: Maybe this is now getting too much into the specifics of my use case, but I usually write: "I would love to have a call. When would be a good time for you?". That's why I like the "would love to" construct; it politely introduces the next question about scheduling. I could say "Please tell me a good time for you", but I'm missing the sentence before it, which introduces the whole calling business. (Not sure if this makes sense..)

Comment: @user1496984 I edited my answer. You can use "would love to" or "would like to". They don't sound unprofessional.

Answer (score 5):

Go with "I would be delighted to..." it conveys what you describe when using "I would love to..."

Answer (score 2):

I often use:

> I would welcome the opportunity to ...

Comment: This is exactly the sentence I was looking for.